Using overall Go code coverage profile to display coverage at a package level
TLDR
Is there a way to display/calculate the coverage percentage at a package level, using the overall coverage profile?
Scenario
I have a Go project with numerous packages and sub-packages:
|root/
|go.mod
|/package1/
|/package1/foo.go
|/package1/foo_test.go
|/package2/
|/package2/subpackage1/
|/package2/subpackage1/foo.go
|/package2/subpackage1/foo_test.go
|/package2/
|/package2/subpackage2/
|/package2/subpackage2/bar.go
|/package2/subpackage2/bar_test.go
...

I want to collect the coverage in percentage for

The overall project
package-level, not sub-packages

For example, I want the coverage information:
package1                   60%
package2                   82%
overall                    78%

To collect the overall coverage, I am running go test -v -coverprofile=c.out ./.... I can then run go tool cover -func=c.out or -html=c.out to get more details, as well as an overall percentage of the project. However, is there an "easy" way to find the percentage per package? I have two possible approaches here:
Approach 1 - I can go inside each package and do the above to get the percentage per package. But it would be a bit tedious going into each package to calculate the c.out, especially when you can calculate the overall consolidated c.out at the root level.
Approach 2 - Write some script to manipulate the overall c.out. Separate the lines for the "target" package. Then run go tool -func at package level.
Both of these seem a bit "manual" or "brute force" to me. I am wondering if there is a more straightforward approach to achieve this? Any suggestion is appreciated.

No. There simply isn’t a thing like „subpackage“.
